# ruby set key of hash for array of hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Given the following array of hashes, how can I make a new hash with `friend_id` as the key and `dist` the value?

```
results = [
 {"user_id"=>"18", "friend_id"=>"17", "dist"=>"1"},
 {"user_id"=>"18", "friend_id"=>"42", "dist"=>"1"},
 {"user_id"=>"18", "friend_id"=>"43", "dist"=>"1"},
 {"user_id"=>"18", "friend_id"=>"46", "dist"=>"2"}
]

desired_hash = {"17" => "1", "42" => "1", "43" => "1", "46" => "2"}
```

I've tried `map` but the values are then in an array. I also tried to `flatten` that result but it flattened the key instead of the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
results.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g["friend_id"]] = g["dist"] }
```

or

```
results.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update(g["friend_id"]=> g["dist"]) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use    [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) method.

```
results.inject({}) {|sum, e| sum.merge({e["friend_id"] => e["dist"]})}
# => {"17"=>"1", "42"=>"1", "43"=>"1", "46"=>"2"}
```

Comment: `merge` on each iteration is quite inefficient.

Comment: Why ? Could you please tell me the reason?

Comment: `h1 = { :a => 1 } ; h2 = { :b => 2 } ; n = 5000000 ; Benchmark.bm do |x| x.report { for i in 1..n; h1.merge h2; end } ; x.report { n.times do   ; h1[:b] = h2[:b]; end } ; end` ⇒ `5.870000` vs. `0.660025`. The reason: hash is updated on every merge.

Answer (score 1):

For this use case, I think it would be simpler and more readable to just use `#each`:

```
desired_hash = Hash.new
results.each {|h| desired_hash[h["friend_id"]] = h["dist"]}
```

Then, desired_hash is:

```
#=> {"17"=>"1", "42"=>"1", "43"=>"1", "46"=>"2"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
desired_hash = Hash[results.map{ |h| [ h['friend_id'], h['dist']] }]
```

or as Victor suggests

```
desired_hash = Hash[results.map{ |x| x.values_at('friend_id', 'dist') }]
```

Comment: I like this approach but you would have to set a new variable to results and use that in the `map` method instead. As it is, this mutates `results` array by adding the `desired_hash` to it:
    `[{"user_id"=>"18", "friend_id"=>"17", "dist"=>"1"}, {"user_id"=>"18", "friend_id"=>"42", "dist"=>"1"}, {"user_id"=>"18", "friend_id"=>"43", "dist"=>"1"}, {"user_id"=>"18", "friend_id"=>"46", "dist"=>"2"}]`

Comment: `h.values_at('friend_id', 'dist')` is probably easier

Answer (score 1):

```
results.map {|h| [h['friend_id'], h['dist']]} .to_h
```

Although I probably like @CarySwoveland 's answer better, on the lines of:

```
results.each_with_object({}) {|h, n| n[h['friend_id']] = h['dist']}
```